# React test library does not work with Modal Portal

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have written a component for Modal Window, put it in createPortal. I wanted to write a test for that, but a got an error:
console.error
Error: Uncaught [Error: Target container is not a DOM element.]
For some reasons test did not see my component. I do not have any idea why it work this way.
If somebody knows, please write, thank you in advance!
My test looks so:

```
test('modal', () => {
  const handleClose = jest.fn();

  const {getByText} = render(<Modal onClose={handleClose} isOpen title={'title'} />);
  expect(getByText('title')).toBeTruthy();
});
```

My component looks so:

```
interface IModalProps {
  isOpen: boolean;
  title?: string;
  className?: string;
  onClose: () => void;
  content?: React.ReactChildren | React.ReactChild
}

const Modal = ({isOpen, title, content, onClose, className}: IModalProps) => {

  const keydownHandler = ({keyCode}:KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (keyCode === 27) {
      onClose();
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', keydownHandler);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', keydownHandler);
  });

  const modalInPortal = () => (
    <div
      className={classNames(
        'modal-overlay',
        isOpen && 'active')}
      onClick={onClose}
    >
      <div
        className={classNames(
          className,
          'modal' )}
        onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
      >
        <div className="modal-block-content">
          <span
            className="close-btn"
            onClick={onClose}
          >
        &times;
          </span>
          <h2 className="modal-title">{title}</h2>
          {content && <div className="modal-body">{content}</div>}
          <div className="modal-footer">
            <Button
              color={'light'}
              style={{color:'blue'}}
              size="lg"
              onClick={onClose}
            >
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button size="lg">Save</Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  return createPortal( modalInPortal(), document.getElementById('portal'));
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, in production, you have a HTML element in your `index.html` that has an `id` of `portal`.

Jest doesn't have that same HTML, so when it tries to portal, it can't find it and blows up.

Usually to fix this, you need to add a [`setupFilesAfterEnv`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array) to your jest config that points to a new file that builds up that HTML outside of React's remit.

Inside this file, you'd have:

```
const portalEl = document.createElement('div')
portalEl.setAttribute('id', 'portal')
document.body.appendChild(portalEl)
```

Now the test environment is like your real one for all tests (this file is globally applied).

When asserting on the contents you will also probably need to use [`screen`](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#screen) since the actual modal is loaded outside the container.